# Why the author has used the Inner Join instead of Left Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using MySQL 8.0, its "Sakila" database to solve a problem which says--

> Find the total number of films for each film rating (G, PG, ...) for each actor.

To give more background, here are the two tables joined and their description:

**Table #1: film**

```
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field                | Type                                                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| film_id              | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| title                | varchar(255)                                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| description          | text                                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| release_year         | year(4)                                                             | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| language_id          | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| original_language_id | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| rental_duration      | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   |     | 3                 |                                               |
| rental_rate          | decimal(4,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 4.99              |                                               |
| length               | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| replacement_cost     | decimal(5,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 19.99             |                                               |
| rating               | enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17')                                  | YES  |     | G                 |                                               |
| special_features     | set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| last_update          | timestamp                                                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**Table #2: film_actor**

```
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| actor_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                                               |
| film_id     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                                               |
| last_update | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

From the question asked, what I understood is that the query should return `count` of all the films from the `film_actor` table, as it mentioned the `rating` column which is only present in the same table. On that basis, I used the `left join` but the author solved it with `inner join`. Could someone please clarify why `inner join` is correct and not `left join`.

Here is my solution:

```
select count(f.film_id), f.rating, fa.actor_id
from film f
left join film_actor fa
on f.film_id = fa.film_id
group by f.rating, fa.actor_id;
```

Solution give by the author:

```
SELECT fa.actor_id, f.rating, count(*)
FROM film_actor fa
INNER JOIN film f
ON fa.film_id = f.film_id
GROUP BY fa.actor_id, f.rating
```

Request to please point out the gap in my understanding and also, please guide me to come up with the correct join to use in such word/scenario based problems.

Comment: may be all films in film table have record in film_actor.

Comment: nope! there are some which are not present in the ```film_actor``` table

Comment: can you share data ?

Comment: If you do a `left join` you will also find films without actor.

Comment: @AmitVerma: The sakila database can be downloaded here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html

Comment: You should use left join, since the count for someone with no films is 0, and the inner join answer is wrong. PS [mre] Put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question of English than of databases.  But the question is implicitly saying:  "Find the total number of films for each rating for each actor *in those films*".  That is why an inner join is appropriate.

In practice, it is reasonable to assume that all actors are in a film.  This may not be true, but it is a reasonable assumption and if true `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` would be the same.

I suspect you are thinking of something a little difference, which would be all ratings for all actors, with the count -- even if there are no films.  That would be phrased slightly differently.  More importantly, a `LEFT JOIN` would not answer this question correctly.